# Find the users of Active Directory global group?

Tags: active-directory, windows-command-prompt, ms-dos, dsquery

I am using following command to get the users of Active Directory Global Group.

```
dsquery group -name "Groupname" |dsget group -members
```

But, this is **piped** command and it's not working in Visual Studio,
Please suggest me any alternative DOS command **without using pipe** which can work on standalone server.

Comment: these are kind of old, can't you use Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer,you can use following command to achieve this

```
dsget group "Group DN Name" -members
```

To get group DN Name you need following command

```
dsquery group -name "Groupname"
```

By using Both command you can get the result.

To run dsget and dsquery command you must have Windows **Remote Server Administrative Tool** Installed and enabled in your system.

Alternatively you can use net user command which doesn't requires elevation and Remote Server Administration Tool both.

```
net user /domain "Groupname"
```